# How to convert pandas dataframe columns into json

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a big pandas dataframe, one of the column name is source_name. I want a output dataframe which will have two columns, json_content and source_name where all the columns except source_name will be converted into json and place under json_content column.

Currently I am doing like this:

```
class CustomJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
            return obj.isoformat()
        elif isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
            return str(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        elif isinstance(obj, np.nan):
            return 'None'
        return super().default(obj)

dict_list = df.to_dict(orient='records')
new_dict_list = [
    {'json_content': json.dumps({k: v for k, v in row.items()
                                 if k not in ['source_name']},
                                cls=CustomJSONEncoder),
     'source_name': row['source_name']} for row in
    dict_list]
df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict_list, columns=['json_content',
                                          'source_name'])
```

But this is taking lots of time to process. Is there any better way to do this?

tried this as well:

```
df = df[['source_name']].assign(
            json_content=df.iloc[:, 1:].agg(dict, 1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the entire dataframe (minus the `source_name` column) to JSON in `lines` format, split that output to a list and assign that as the new column:

```py
df = df[['source_name']].assign(
    json_content=df.drop('source_name', axis=1).to_json(orient='records', lines=True).splitlines())
```

Comment: can you please explain why this will improve performance? also will it use all available cpu core?

Comment: also if in my input dataframe any value is in dateformat or np.ndarray then how it will handle?

Comment: @Dcook I would expect it to be more efficient as it's converting the whole df to json at once rather than on a row-by-row basis. As to whether it would use all available cpu cores, I'm not familiar enough with the internals of pandas to answer that. But I don't see why the `to_json` could not be farmed out on a one core/row basis.

Comment: @Dcook you can still provide your custom encoder to `to_json` using the `default_handler` parameter

Comment: in some cases I am getting memory error with the above json conversion

Comment: @Dcook How big is your dataframe? Can you post some sample data so I can try playing with it?